# How to do sum of the numbers displayed on webpage in selenium webdriver with java

Tags: java, selenium

**My Scenario**

"Go to:
  http://www.americangolf.co.uk/golf-clubs/fairway-woods"

Print every link under brand

Every link will have a number in front of it

Find sum of all numbers

Total number of products found is written on the page-"49 Products found"

Verify sum s equal to number of products mentioned

**My Code**

```
public class americangolf {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.americangolf.co.uk/golf-clubs/fairway-woods");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        List<WebElement> elem = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='secondary']/div[1]/div[3]/div/ul/li/a"));
        for(WebElement li:elem)
        {
            System.out.println(li.getText());
        }

        List<WebElement> elem1 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='secondary']/div[1]/div[3]/div/ul/li/a/span[2]"));

        for(WebElement li1:elem1)
        {
            System.out.println(li1.getText());
        }

        int con= Integer.parseInt(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='secondary']/div[1]/div[3]/div/ul/li/a/span[2]")).getText());

        for(int i=0;i<elem1.size();i++)
        {
            int sum = i+con;
            System.out.println("Total is:"+sum);
        }
    }
}
```

**Console output**

```
CobraGolf (10)
CallawayGolf (9)
TaylorMade (7)
Ping (6)
WilsonStaff (4)
NikeGolf (3)
Benross (2)
Titleist (2)
Wilson (2)
Fazer (1)
MizunoGolf (1)
USKidsGolf (1)
YONEX (1)
(10)
(9)
(7)
(6)
(4)
(3)
(2)
(2)
(2)
(1)
(1)
(1)
(1)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "(10)"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at module13.americangolf.main(americangolf.java:39)
```

I am getting the above error while doing the sum of all printed numbers. I don't know how to get rid of it. Any solutions to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following:

```
    public class americangolf {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.americangolf.co.uk/golf-clubs/fairway-woods");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        List<WebElement> elem = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='refinement brand']/descendant::a"));
        for(WebElement li:elem)
        {
            System.out.println(li.getText());
        }

        List<WebElement> elem1 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='refinement brand']/descendant::a/span[2]"));
        int sum = 0;
        for(WebElement li1:elem1)
        {
            System.out.println(li1.getText());
            String s = li1.getText().replace("(", "");
            sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(s.replace(")", ""));
        }


        System.out.println("Total sum is: " + sum);

        int totalAppearingOnPage = Integer.parseInt(driver.findElement(
                By.xpath("//h1[normalize-space(text())='Best Selling Fairway woods']/following::div[@class='results-hits'][1]/span")).
                getText());
        System.out.println("Total appearing on page: " + totalAppearingOnPage);
        driver.quit();
    }
    }
```

In the above code, I have enhanced the **xpaths** in order to minimize the impact of UI changes. Let me know, if you have any further queries.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the whole string (with the parentheses) to sum.

one solution (definitely not the best one) is to replace this:

```
int con= Integer.parseInt(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='secondary']/div[1]/div[3]/div/ul/li/a/span[2]")).getText());
```

for this:

```
int con= Integer.parseInt(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='secondary']/div[1]/div[3]/div/ul/li/a/span[2]")).getText().replace("(","").replace(")","");
```

By doing that, you'll be able to parse as an Integer